# Downgrading Python Version and Got an Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

I am a beginner in Python who wants to use TensorFlow. 
I have previously used Python v3.7.4 but then downgraded to Python 3.6.10.
However, now I experience problems in that I cannot run a single code.
Here is the problem as mentioned in Anaconda Prompt.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 546, in _run_callback
    result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 258, in open
    super(ZMQChannelsHandler, self).open()
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\zmqhandlers.py", line 168, in open
    self.send_ping, self.ping_interval, io_loop=loop,
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'

[![Io Loop Error][1]][1]
```

Comment: It's likely that previously installed libraries and packages are still installed and not compatible with the older version of Python. You would do well to set up a separate environment and reinstall the packages you need for the correct version of Python.

Comment: @Grismar how would you recommend me to check which packages I need to install in order to solve the problem? I need to stick with Python 3.6.10 in order to use TensorFlow

Comment: @TonyFlager you should re-install **all of them**. You should have been doing this using a seperate `conda` environment in the first place. It's still what you should do.

Comment: problem is solved based on conda cheatsheet, thank you!

Comment: What are the contents of the environment?

Answer (score 0):

conda is actually there to help you avoid these problems. As a rule of thumb, you should not work on your base environment. Always make use of environments.

How to fix your issue.
1. Roll back to stage that was working 
2. Create environment for your project

Code:

```sh
# this will list the revision numbers 
conda list --revisions
# take the second last number N
conda install --revision N
```

This will restore your conda before everything broke. Meaning you will have Python 3.7 again

```sh
conda create -n tensor python=3.6 tensorflow
conda activate tensor

# test tensorflow
python -c "import tensorflow;print(tensorflow.__version.__)"
```

Now you have base environment with Python 3.7 and tensor environment with Python 3.6. When you want to work with tensorflow, you just activate this environment and work in there.

Adding packages

```
# to deactivate
conda deactivate
```

It is good practice to create environment for each project you work in.